How gifts affect estate tax (USA)
Scenario:
Daughter might purchase a house from us for $400,000.
We give her "equity credit" as part or all of the down payment.  (She has been renting it from us and total rents exceeded that.)
If that happened this year (2024) that is the annual gift tax exclusion of $18,000 and a $12,000 reduction in the lifetime exclusion (from 27,220K for a couple to 27,208K).
But since my wife and I are two, and daughter is married, we actually can give them 72K (more than thirty!) without even affecting the lifetime exclusion.
And if we pass with an estate valued at only two million, there would be no federal estate tax.
(There's still a tax in our state, though)
Some of the numbers altered for simplicity.
Am I misinterpreting any part of this?  True for an outright gift, but when it is credit for the purchase, does that change the rules?

You can exclude the first 18K (as of 2024) from the value of the total gifts to the same donee. See the IRC Sec. 2503(b). With split gifting you can exclude 36K for each donee. So if it's your daughter and her partner then you can exclude, together with your spouse, up to 72K.

True for an outright gift, but when it is credit for the purchase, does that change the rules?

Not entirely sure what you mean by "credit for purchase". Not familiar with such a concept.

But since my wife and I are two, and daughter is married, we actually can give them 72K (more than thirty!) without even affecting the lifetime exclusion.

Up to 72K. However, remember that future interest is not included in that exclusion, the way you described that transaction that may be relevant to you.

And if we pass with an estate valued at only two million, there would be no federal estate tax.

According to the current law. That may change by the time of your passing. However your estate won't be taxed retroactively on the portion of the lifetime exclusion already used up.

From a non-IRS source: “Any amount you give over the annual limit is subtracted from your larger lifetime limit.”  https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/gift-tax-rate

You're right, I'll edit the answer

"credit for purchase"—"equity credit" is what the mortgage broker called it.  I used the same term, though it doesn't make sense to me, since they have no equity in the property.  Means that much of the already paid rent is considered down payment.

@WGroleau was it considered that when it was paid? How did you declare it for taxes? Is there a written agreement mentioning that? This sounds to me like something you'd want to run through an attorney, not a mortgage salesman.

That was the original intent, though in our taxes, it is treated as a rental on Schedule E (which it is how it will remain until if & when she actually decides to buy it).
